# I ran appcfg.py update but do not see changes

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I just inherited an application written in python and hosted on Google App Engine. I've never used App Engine before so I'm not sure if I'm missing something here.

I made some changes and ran the `appcfg.py update .` command from within my app's root directory. And it seems to succeed as I get this:

```
05:05 PM Scanning files on local disk.
05:05 PM Cloning 160 static files.
05:05 PM Cloning 122 application files.
05:05 PM Compilation starting.
05:05 PM Compilation completed.
05:05 PM Starting deployment.
05:05 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
05:05 PM Deployment successful.
05:05 PM Checking if updated app version is serving.
05:05 PM Completed update of app: echofonads, version: 6
```

However, then I go to the site and the change is not reflected. Is there a way to confirm that my changes were in fact successfully deployed to App Engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely have a default version which is different than the one you just uploaded.

You can see your versions and which one is your default serving by clicking **Versions** on the left hand navigation pane of the [Admin Console](https://appengine.google.com).

(You can also access this in the new [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com) by clicking **Compute** > **App Engine** > **Versions**)

You can see a log of all version uploads by clicking **Admin Logs** in the left navigation pane.